# Use Handlebars.js with Backbone.Marionette

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, marionette

Is it possible to use the Handlebars.js with the [Backbone.Marionette](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette) extension without reimplementing the Views render function? It seems that Marionette is relying on the convention that you use Backbone.js with underscores templating engine. But I really like the handlebar approach so I'm asking if I can the high-level-tools of Marionette with handlebars.

Comment: There's something about Marionette and Handlebars integration in Marionette's wiki, check it out: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/Using-handlebars-templates-with-marionette

Comment: check this link: 
[link][1]

hope it helps
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501516/backbone-marionette-i18n-handlebars/11505302#11505302

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A simple way to use Handlebars with Marionette is simply to define `template` in each View as a pre-compiled Handlebars template function.  For instance:

```
var MyView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: Handlebars.compile("Hello, {{name}}"),
    model: new Backbone.Model({name: "Steve"})
});
```

Marionette's default `Renderer` will detect that the `template` attribute is a function, and will call it accordingly.

See also the official documentation about this case : https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/Using-handlebars-templates-with-marionette

and an other Q/A with requirejs  + Marionette + Handlebars precompiled : [Using precompiled handlebars templates with Marionette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863285/using-precompiled-handlebars-templates-with-marionette)

Answer (score 6):

@brettjonesdev is correct, but one other addition here that I found worked well was:

```
var MyView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: Handlebars.compile($("#assign-products-main-view").html()),
  model: new Backbone.Model({name: "Steve"})
});
```

This helps when searching the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

We can also make use of precompiled templates here.

```
var MyView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
template: Handlebars.templates['filename'],
model: new Backbone.Model({name: "Steve"})
});
```

This way we can remove the compilation role from Marionette.

Answer (score 2):

The current two answers do not exploit caching. Use this gist [instead.](https://gist.github.com/funkjedi/5732611)