# Using precompiled handlebars templates with Marionette

Tags: requirejs, handlebars.js, marionette

I'm using Marionette with requirejs and I would also like to use precompiled handlebars templates.
How does this work?

Here my current setup:

require_main.js:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "/",
    paths: {
        'text': 'vendor/javascripts/text',
        'backbone': "vendor/javascripts/backbone",
        'backbone.wreqr': "vendor/javascripts/backbone.wreqr",
        'backbone.babysitter': "vendor/javascripts/backbone.babysitter",
        'jquery': "vendor/javascripts/jquery",
        'jquery-ui': 'vendor/javascripts/jquery-ui',
        'json2': "vendor/javascripts/json2",
        'marionette': "vendor/javascripts/backbone.marionette",
        'underscore': "vendor/javascripts/underscore",
        'handlebars': "vendor/javascripts/handlebars"
    },

    shim: {
        'underscore': {
            exports: "_"
        },
        'backbone': {
            deps: ["jquery", "underscore", "json2"],
            exports: "Backbone"
        },
        'marionette': {
            deps: ["backbone"],
            exports: "Marionette"
        },
        'jquery-ui': ['jquery'],

    'handlebars': {
      exports: 'Handlebars'
    }
    }
});
require(["app"], function(MyApp){
    MyApp.start();
});
```

app.js:

```
define(['marionette', 'handlebars', 'text!compiled.handlebars'], function(Marionette, Handlebars, Template_one) {

    var MyApp = new Marionette.Application();

    MyApp.addRegions({
        mainRegion: "#main-region"
    });

    MyApp.StaticView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: Template_one(context)
    });

    MyApp.on("initialize:after", function(){
        var staticView = new MyApp.StaticView();
        MyApp.mainRegion.show(staticView);  
    });

});
```

in my app.js I can get evth. work just fine with non compiled templates, like this:

```
...
var template = Handlebars.compile(Template_one)
var html = template(context)
template: html
...
```

but how to do it right with compiled templates?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Update: With Handlebars precompiler only

The reason I mentioned `Grunt` earlier is because it comes very handy for a [LOT of things](http://gruntjs.com/plugins). So, in my opinion, it's very important to know/learn about it.

But you can achieve the exact same thing with the [Handlebars precompiler](http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html) alone:

```
$ handlebars templates/* -f js/precompiled.handlebars.js
```

You still have to integrate `precompiled.handlebars.js` in your RequireJS config, see at the end of the answer.

### Original: With Grunt

You'll need the [Grunt Task Runner](http://gruntjs.com/) for that, it makes these kind of things a LOT easier.

From now on, I'm assuming the following folder structure:

```
project/
    assets/
        js/
        templates/
```

I'm also assuming you have [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) installed on your machine!

---

### Installing Grunt

```
$ cd project/assets/
$ sudo npm install grunt --save-dev
```

### Installing Handlebars Plugin

You'll also need the Handlebars [Grunt plugin](http://gruntjs.com/plugins) in order to precompile your templates:

- [grunt-contrib-handlebars](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-handlebars)

Install it like this:

```
$ sudo npm install grunt-contrib-handlebars --save-dev
```

### Gruntfile.js

*Notes*:

- A `Gruntfile.js` is a configuration file for Grunt
- It lives at the root of where is installed your Grunt CLI instance
- It's written in plain javascript

Create the file:

```
$ touch Gruntfile.js
```

Then copy/paste this typical `Gruntfile` for accomplishing what you want to achieve:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  /*
   * https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Configuring-tasks
   */
  grunt.initConfig({

    "handlebars": {
      compile: {
        options: {
          amd: true
        },
        src: ["templates/**/*.html"],
        dest: "js/precompiled.handlebars.js"
      }
    }

  });

  // Requires the needed plugin
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-handlebars');
};
```

All plugin options [here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-handlebars).

### Running the task

Then, assuming that you have templates living in `assets/templates/`, run:

```
$ grunt handlebars:compile
```

If everything is ok you should be able to see your compiled templates in `js/precompiled.handlebars.js`:

```
define([

    // Should be `handlebars.runtime.js` here
    // See: http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html
    'handlebars'

], function(Handlebars) {

  this["JST"] = this["JST"] || {};

  this["JST"]["templates/template_one.html"] = Handlebars.template(function(Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) { /* ... */ });

  this["JST"]["templates/template_two.html"] = Handlebars.template(function(Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) { /* ... */ });

  //...

  return this["JST"];

});
```

### Integration with RequireJS

Obviously, in your `Views`, you'll have to change your dependencies:

```
define([
  'marionette',
  //'handlebars', /* You don't need this _here_ anymore */
  'js/compiled.handlebars'

], function(Marionette, JST) {

    /* edited for brevity */

    MyApp.StaticView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: JST["templates/template_one.html"]
    });

    MyApp.on("initialize:after", function(){
        var staticView = new MyApp.StaticView();
        MyApp.mainRegion.show(staticView);  
    });
});
```

Comment: I wish I could vote twice, Very Helpful! Is there any way I can simplify accessing the template instead of using the file relative path as the key?

Comment: I don't think so. But there may be an option in the Handlebars precompiler.

Comment: I found an option called `processName`.

    handlebars: {
        compile: {
          options: {
            amd: true,
            processName: function(filePath) {
          var pieces = filePath.split("/");
       return pieces[pieces.length - 1].split(".")[0];
      }
         },
         src: ['src/js/templates/*.handlebars'],
         dest: 'src/js/templates.js'
      }
    }

Comment: I can't get this to work... Can you maybe provide a gist with some examples? It keeps saying that in cannot call function 'template' of undefined (which should be Handlebars)