# how can I use external templates with Marionette Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

How exactly do I use an external template for my Marionette ItemView? 
I read so many 'methods' I can't get any of them working...

**JST Method ... I'm not on rails so can't use this**

```
Backbone.Marionette.Renderer.render = (template, data) ->
    path = JST["backbone/apps/" + template]
    unless path
        throw "Template #{template} not found!"
    path(data)
```

**RequireJS Method ... I'm not using require js**

```
var tpl = require(inject[this.templateName]);
this.template = _.template(tpl);
```

What method should I be using?

Comment: I think this may help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703896/use-handlebars-js-with-backbone-marionette

Comment: same problem with handlebars, how do I get the content of the handlebar template file...

Comment: You may use this approach http://johndavidmathis.wordpress.com/2012/09/13/preloading-backbone-marionette-templates-2/

Answer (score 1):

I use Handlebars for my templating engine and [hbs](https://github.com/SlexAxton/require-handlebars-plugin) to retrieve the precompiled resource via require.js, that way all I have to do is define the template and set it as the ItemView's template; marionette does the rest.

Here's an example

View - welcome.js

```
define([
    'app',
    'jquery', 
    'backbone',
    'marionette', 
    'hbs!templates/welcome'
    ],
function(App, $, Backbone, Marionette, template) {

    return Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

        template: template,
    });
});
```

Template - welcome.html

```
<div>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>
```

If you're not using handlebars, or can't use hbs, then something similar can be done with text.js - https://github.com/requirejs/text